# jQuery fullcalendar - display event title down side

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use jQuery the fullcalendar plugin to create a schedule view for inventory item bookings, but I'm having some difficulties. Inside the system, a user can create a booking for an item between a given start and end date. By default, treating a booking for an item as an event, I can use fullcalendar to display any items that have bookings in a calendar, as in the following screenshot.[image]

This is pretty straight forward, however the preferred functionality would be to have a list of all items down the side as a legend (with or without bookings), then for any items that have bookings, display the event. The best way for me to explain this is to show a mockup of what I'd like to do:
[image]

I've mucked around with fullcalendar but I can't seem to be able to get it to display the items down the side like in my screenshot. I've searched for examples / other plugins but I haven't been able to find anything that implements this kind of functionality. For the time being I'm not fussed about having the empty items displayed, I'm sure that wouldn't be too hard to achieve later, but for now I would just like to get the items displayed down the side.

Has anyone seen anything like this, or have any examples or ideas that could put me on the right track to solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think a bunch of people want a "resource" view:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150